# unset form elements with hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms

I've created my module, but I have a problem when its code executes the following code:

```
dpm($form);
```

I can't see the notifications fields (from the [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) module); also, I can't remove the "Format" fieldset from the node create page ("node/add/question"; my content type is called "question").

The following snippet works great, but is there any other method to print all the form's fieldsets? I just stuck at this notifications field set, as I can't remove it.

```
unset($form['menu'], $form['comment_settings']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notification does add its own form elements in its own `hook_form_alter()`, which is probably executed after yours.

Check the module weight in the {system} table, and set your module to a higher value to have it run later.

Note: Instead of using `unset()` to hide form elements, you should instead set the `#access` property to `FALSE`. This keeps them in the form build tree, which avoids problems if other modules try to access or alter that information.

Comment: notifications placed in {notifications} table not in system. Thanks for the note. What it might be?

Comment: No, *every* module has a row in the {system} table that stores the which which influences the order in which implementations of a hook are invoked. The {notifications} table has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Oh, sorry found it. Both notifications and my module has 0 weight.

Comment: @Heihachi If both the modules have the same weight, then they are executed in alphabetical order, which means, for example, that the Local module is executed before the Menu module.

Comment: I agree: Setting the `#access` property is better than using `unset()` on the form field. It doesn't create problems with the validation handlers, which could return an error for the form field not having the expected value, and with the submission handlers, which would not save the value for that form field (and save instead a default value).

Comment: i've set weight of my module 9999 still can't remove that crap... wtf

Comment: Thanks, berdir. Now i see all that crap in $form array :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to do what you need to do using the `#after_build` form property.